# Export tensorflow weights to hdf5 file and model to keras model.json

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5

I recently found this [Project](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js) which runs inference of keras model in a browser with GPU support using webgl. I have a few tensorflow project that I would like to run inference on a browser, is there a way to export tensorflow models into hdf5 file so it can be run using keras-js

Comment: You can check my answer on this issue in another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466066/how-can-i-convert-a-trained-tensorflow-model-to-keras/46210187#46210187

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keras, you can do something like this.

```
model.save_weights('my_model.hdf5')
```

Comment: No I am using tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is if you use a `Keras` model as an interface to your `TensorFlow` workflow. If you do that, you can do this to save the model and its weights:

```
# save model
with open(model_save_filename, "w") as model_save_file:
    model_json = model.to_json()
    model_save_file.write(model_json)

# save model weights
model.save_weights(model_weights_save_filename)
```

More information on using `Keras` as an interface to `Tensorflow` workflows here: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#using-keras-models-with-tensorflow